# Getting value from this JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been experimenting with writing JQuery plugins lately, and I'm sure this is a very simple question. But, I seem to not be able to get a value inside of my plugin.

For example, I have the following code:

plugin.js

```
$(function($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // alert the id from main.js
  }
});
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#someDIV').attr('id').myPlugin();
});
```

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9kb9g8nv/

Comment: Copied the wrong code, updated

Comment: `.attr()` returns a string, not a jQuery object. Do as Tushar has in the jsFiddle

Comment: Why is the code in the old edit wrong if it works?

Comment: Because I don't want to get the id attribute from the plugin function its self, I want to pass it in with calling the plugin as seen above

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define plugin on `string`. Use `selector` to call the plugin.

Have a look at [this](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#basic-plugin-authoring).

Use it like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            // Allow multiple element selectors
            alert(this.attr('id'));
        });

        return this; // Allow Chaining
    }
} (jQuery));

$('.myClass').myPlugin();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9kb9g8nv/)

[**Tutorial**](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: And you can just do `this.attr('id')` http://jsfiddle.net/2vuLkc3m/ `this` is already jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }
}(jQuery));
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/1cgub37y/1/

Comment: And you can just do `this.attr('id')` http://jsfiddle.net/2vuLkc3m/ `this` is already jQuery object

Comment: @NickDugger, Go through my fiddle and comment

Answer (score 0):

You should pass only the object into your jQuery-extension function (not the object's ID), as below or in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odg7g12b/) (will alert "someDIV" onload):

```
// jQuery extension
// The object passed into jQuery extension will occupy keyword "this"
$(function($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
      // Get the ID (or some other attr) of the object.
      var id = $(this).attr("id");

      // Now do something with it :)
      alert(id);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#someDIV').myPlugin();
});
```